# How to send GET request without any parameter in EXT-JS

Tags: extjs, callback, request, script-tag

In *Java script* when we send GET request it goes without adding any parameter, But in *EXT-JS* it auto add CallBack parameter. (i checked with Wireshark & firebug)

we are able to see xml on browser on Juniper MFC  URL, because it sends GET request, but browser show 404 error when *REQUEST* sent with any parameter like 'callback parameter' *(acc to Firebug, browser & wireshark)*.

So i need to create a new proxy Extend from *ScriptTagProxy,* in that modified load function.
Please tell me how i can do that.

I have done the following but no luck.

```
        var _Proxy = Ext.extend(Ext.data.MyScriptTagProxy({
         url: 'http://IP:PORT/App',
         method: 'GET',
         nocache: false,
         restful: true 
         }); 

 Ext.define('Ext.data.MyScriptTagProxy' {   
 extend: 'Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy',
 constructor:function(cnfg){
 this.callParent(arguments);//Calling the parent class constructor
      this.initConfig(cnfg);//Initializing the component
      this.on('beforerender',this.beforeRender);
 }});
```

IF there is another solution for topic also please suggest.

Comment: Why does it have to be a ScripTagProxy?

Comment: HI themel,
I need to send request to another domain... so can i send only GET request there, without any parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution,

My prob :- Mentioned in Qus.

My Solution :- I send Request to Server via AJAX, than save the responsetext, Convert the same into XML via jQuery. then give this value to data field of XMLStore. 
since server is in another domain, so also disabled POP-Up blocker.
  tool using: - ExtDesigner

My code :- (Sorry for code quality)

```
var doc = sendReq();

function sendReq() {
    var xmlstr = SendRequest();
    var doc1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

    doc1.async = "false";
    doc1.loadXML(xmlstr);
    alert(" Xml is parsing ... ");

    return doc1;
}

function SendRequest() {
    var Url = "http://SERVER_IP:PORT/XMLPATH";

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
    xmlHttp.open("GET", Url, false);
    xmlHttp.send();

    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

function ProcessRequest() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        if (xmlHttp.responseText != "Not found") {
            var str = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}

MyStore = Ext.extend(Ext.data.XmlStore, {
    constructor: function (cfg) {
        cfg = cfg || {};
        MyStore.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
            storeId: 'MyStore',
            data: doc,
            record: 'resourcePool',
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: [{
                name: 'bandwidth',
                type: 'float'
            }, {
                name: 'name',
                type: 'string'
            }]

        }, cfg));
    }
});

new MyStore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem: in order to use JsonP (ScriptTagProxy) your server needs to wrap the response into a javascript method callback and return valid JavaScript code. Any other format will fail because the request is executed using `<script>` tags and the response will be interpreted by the browser's JavaScript engine.

Furthermore, the client needs to be able to match the callback to the original request - this is why ExtJs sends the name of the callback method, which is unique for that specific request.

But before we delve into this, are you aware that JsonP requires the server to prepare the response data accordingly. Does your server (Juniper MFC) support this?

As an alternative you can go with `CORS` which was introduced as an alternative to JsonP. This technique is less invasive and requires a special HTTP header configuration for your HTML document(s) on the server.
ExtJs supports `CORS` via [Ext.data.Connection#cors](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-cfg-cors).

Comment: Hi mistaecko,

      (1) CORS is use with XDomainRequest only, server not allowing this object bcoz of security reason.
(2) These MFC device(server) only reply an xml in text format, no Callback, no wrapping data. 
 So Plz Suggest me : -
        (1) How to send get Request without callBack parameter or any parameter to server that is in other domain.
  or (2) how to override load function of ScriptTagProxy, where i can stop adding CallBack parameter in My Request.
  Thanks in Advance,
  Regard Mayank.

Comment: re (1) CORS/XDomainRequest: This applies to IE only, correct? ExtJs will use XDomainRequest when CORS is enabled (ExtJs4.1).

Everything else has been said already...